# Problems with partitions [slurm + Nextflow]

Tags: partition, slurm, nextflow

I've tested the Nextflow's [*sarek*](https://nf-co.re/sarek/2.7.1) pipeline in a *slurm*-based cluster. I'm having an error I cannot fix...

```
Error executing process > 'get_software_versions'
Caused by:
  Failed to submit process to grid scheduler for execution
Command executed:
  sbatch .command.run
Command exit status:
  1
Command output:
  sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: No partition specified or system default partition
```

...and this is my `nextflow.config` file:

```
executor {
    name = 'slurm'
    cpus = 10
    memory = '10 GB'
    queue = 'short'
}
```

I guess is something related with partition assignation. I also tried change `queue = 'short'` by `clusterOptions = '-p short'`, just in case, but it keeps failing.

Any idea about what I'm miss-considering, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead setting the `process.executor` value to [`slurm`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html#slurm) in your `nextflow.config`:

```
process {

  executor = 'slurm'
  queue = 'short'
}
```

The [executor scope](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-executor) just lets you set some optional executor settings. Note that if the `cpus` and `memory` settings are applied here, they will only be used with the `local` executor.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Steve, it works nicely! Question: what I'm trying to do is to execute _sarek_ through _singularity_ in a local cluster and not in AWS, so I guess it's not a problem to specify `memory` and `cpus`, right?

Comment: @jgarces It's not a problem, but you won't need them. If those values are specified in the _executor_ scope, they will have no effect if you submit your jobs using the slurm executor. I haven't run the _sarek_ pipeline before, but it should set some sensible defaults for the jobs it creates. If not, you can [override](https://nf-co.re/sarek/2.7.1/usage#custom-resource-requests) `memory` and `cpus` in the _process_ scope.

Comment: @jgarces The _local_ executor just runs the pipeline processes on the machine where Nextflow is launched.